# VueJs set custom attribute value in select option

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

I'm using vuejs with laravel ..
what I want is to access custom attribute called price like this ..

```
<select name='unit[]' required @change='change_unit($event)'>
    <option v-for='(unit) in line.units' price='66'  :value='unit.get_unit_id.id'>@{{unit['get_unit_id']['name']}}</option>
</select>
```

and this is the vuejs code

```
change_unit:function(event)
{
    let get_val = event.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("price");
    console.log("Value from the Attribute: ", get_val)
}
```

like this everything working so good ..
but my problem is when I want to set the price based one the v-for like this ..

```
<option v-for='(unit) in line.units' price='unit.price' >
```

in console I gat text `'unit.price'` not the real number come from v-for in the loop ..
so how can I set the attribute price based on unit.price..
thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `price` attribute. [binding attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

```
<option v-for='(unit) in line.units' :price='unit.price'>
```